# CSS HTML Semantics and Positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a site with this design and layout for my main-content area: 
http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/9483/screenshot20120429at124.png

However, I'm finding it a little difficult to write up the HTML and CSS using proper semantics.
Firstly, should I be using divs to split the left and right columns, or, HTML5 section tags with an aside tag for the picture?

Secondly, what is the best way to position each section or area?

And finally, with that being said, at the bottom of each content area there are 2 buttons that should be horizontally inline.  What is the best way to go about achieving this considering the fact the the user of the site will later on be placing in their own text and both buttons should push or position themselves further down as more text is placed inside.

This jsfiddle is currently what's making it work...but, seems wrong?
http://jsfiddle.net/LGEKW/

Should those 2 buttons be in that current div, do I use position absolute, relative or floats … I have no idea.  Any help on how you would go about doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your 2 buttons should be at the end of their respective columns in the HTML code. If you want them horizontally aligned, then it's more complicated. They should then be absolutely positioned relative to `#maincontent` at the bottom and superposition of text can be avoided by sufficient padding-bottom on the latter. Buttons will display in the "padding zone".

Comment: (cont) if both columns weren't floats but `display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;` (and `display: table; table-layout:fixed` on `#maincontent`)  then those buttons could easily be placed at the bottom with absolute positioning relative to their column and not relative to some ancestor. But this value of display is compatible with IE8+ and you're stuck with other methods or polyfills for IE7-

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Felipe. Could you please demonstrate this within a jsfiddle.  I'll understand if it's a bit much to ask.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are using `<!doctype html>` it's definitely better to use
   semantic tags, because `divs` have NO semantic meaning at all.
2. To my mind the best way to position the elements is to use `float`
   property
3. The buttons should be floated as well. Not `absolutely positioned`.
   Thus they will be pushed down when the user adds more content. Try placing them after the content in the same wrapper
4. Drop your `br` tags after each paragraph. `p` elements are
   block-level - so you can use `margin-bottom` property to push the
   next `p` down a bit

Comment: Thank you for responding so quick skip405.  I'll use the <section> tags to divide the areas, floating each left and right, and an <aside> tag for the picture.  An additional div below that will contain the the two buttons that will bump down with more text placed within each section.  I have placed the necessary css to my paragraphs as you suggested.

Comment: I would also recommend to avoid applying `display: inline-block` and `float` property at the same time. Because floats become block level automatically. Advise you to delete the `display` property as it's not applied.